# speeding up a slow MySQL query (count) and maybe using MySQL to do stats

Tags: mysql

```
Table soldItem
item ID  |  userID  | store
101.     |  9 .     | Ithica

Table Items
item ID  | . itemCategory
chairs . | . furniture


Table users
userid .  |  userLocation .  | active
123 .     | .NY              | 1 (BOOL)
```

i have a fully working MySQL query that returns exactly what i want from a database... it returns a table that COUNTS THE TOTAL NUMBER TIMES ANY ITEM WAS SOLD FROM WITHIN CATEGORY BY A ANY USER THAT MATCHES A USERID LOCATION CRITERIA. The table spits out a list of userIDs and then counts items sold like this

```
USERID |  COUNT OF TOTAL ITEMS MEETING CRITERIA
AAAA . | . 1123
BBBB . | . 213
```

i then run statistics on the column of counts (mean, min, max, median, SD)

the soldItem table contains 300K records. here is the query i run, it is taking 1.5 seconds and I run it multiple times and then run stats on the results in php to generate a final table

```
select  `userid`, count(`itemID`) as count FROM `soldItem` 
  WHERE `store` = 1 AND `itemID` IN 
    (SELECT  `itemID` FROM  `ITEMS` WHERE  `itemCategory` = 1) 
   AND 
    `userid` IN 
    (SELECT `userid` FROM `users` WHERE `userLocation` = 'NY' AND `active` =1) 
    GROUP BY `userid`
```

i'm wondering if i can speed it up. I run this multiple times with around 15 "itemCategories" and then calculate the Min, Max, Mean, Median and SD. If I could run it all at once on MySQL to save time that would work, reporting a table to my server like:

```
itemCategory | . min . | . max . | mean . | sd
1 .          | . 33 .  | .  55 . | 40 .   | 33
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the table definitions of your tables as well as an `EXPLAIN` result of your SELECT statement. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ok, i made edits, i didnt want to make it to lengthy but i hope this clarifies